# How to force an element with position:absolute to resize the parent div?

Tags: html, css, height, absolute

Easy question. I just want to understand the logic. Why elements with position:absolute (and float:left too) do not "take up space" like position:relative? And how to force an element with position:absolute to resize the parent div?

[View DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rdllngr/fszdh7js/5/)

I need to understand this condition to solve some problems.

```
<style>
    .relative,
    .absolute {
        height: auto;
        width: 200px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 10px;
    }

.relative svg {
        position: relative;
}

.absolute svg {
        position: absolute;
}
</style>


<!-- The height:auto works! -->
<div class="relative">
    <svg width="50" height="50">
        <rect width="50" height="50" style="fill:rgb(255,0,0)" />
    </svg>
</div>

<!-- The height:auto don't works -->
<div class="absolute">
    <svg width="50" height="50">
        <rect width="50" height="50" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`position: absolute` breaks normal flow...

> The normal flow of the document is how your elements stack one on top
>   of each other, from the top down, in the order in which they appear in
>   your markup.
>
> Unlike the static and relative values, an absolutely positioned
>   element is removed from the normal flow. This means you can put it
>   anywhere, and it won’t affect or be affected by any other element in
>   the flow.

Source: http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

CSS SPEC: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html